# Android while touch and touch release

Tags: java, android, touch

Hi, I have recently started trying to make android apps
and have currently made a few simple ones, but, I am still really confused with the touch methods.

What I'm trying to do is: When your finger is held down on the screen, `x` increments, but it stops when you release your finger. The problem is that I can't find any method or any way of doing this.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class zombView extends SurfaceView{
    private Bitmap bmp, grass, joystick;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    Timer t = new Timer();
    float x = 0, y = 0;
    boolean forward;
    public zombView(Context context) {
          super(context);
          holder = getHolder();
          holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

                 @Override
                 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder) {


                     t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
                         public void run(){
                        Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                        onDraw(c);
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        if(forward == true){
                            x++;
                        }
                     }
                 },200,200);
                 }
                 @Override
                 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                               int width, int height) {
                 }
          });
          bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
          grass = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.grassland);
          joystick = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.joystic);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
          canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
          canvas.drawBitmap(grass, getWidth() - getWidth(), getHeight() - getHeight(), null);
          canvas.drawBitmap(joystick, getWidth() - getWidth(),joystick.getHeight(), null);
          canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          if(event.getX() > 10 && event.getX() < 1000){
              if(event.getY() > 10 && event.getY() < 1000){
                  x++;
              }
          }
          return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The `MotionEvent` class has a `getAction` method, which specifies what kind of event did your `onTouchEvent` method has just received. There are three actions that you will use more often:

- `ACTION_DOWN`, which tells you that the user has just put his finger on the screen;
- `ACTION_MOVE`, which tells that the user is still holding his finger on the screen;
- `ACTION_UP`, which tells that the user has taken his finger off the screen.

Depending on what kind of event has just been acquired by your listener you can change the behavior of your code. For more information check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html). Hope this helps.